# Indent all lines of code pasted via code sample

Tags: support, questions, code-formatting

I often want to paste a code snippet into a SO question which has a hierarchical structure (indented with tabs):

```
<div class="some-class">
    <div class="some-class" style="width:130px;">
        <input class="some-class" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If I click "code sample" and paste the code, the result is

```
<div class="some-class">
<div class="some-class" style="width:130px;">
    <input class="some-class" />
</div>
```

Obviously, only the first line of code is indented. Couldn't this be changed to get a more consistent user experience?

Answer (score 3):

I see; I think the issue here is the expectation that once you've started a code sample, subsequent newlines (including via paste) will continue to be automatically indented. Simply: that isn't what happens. However, if you just change the order, it will work fine.

- paste the code (without worrying about indenting it)
- *select* it
- hit the code sample button or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

result: the entire thing indents correctly.